# "One another" when an ordered series of events or stages is involved

Tags: style-manuals, agreement, pronominal-agreement

> According to a traditional rule, *each other* denotes a reciprocal
> relation between two entities, and *one another* refers to more than
> two.
>
> Many people maintain a further stylistic distinction between the two
> expressions by using ***one another*** when an ordered series of
> events or stages is involved, as in *The waiters followed ***one
> another*** into the room*.
>
> https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=each+other

Why is it a "further" distinction?

Doesn't a series of events imply more than two "events" and therefore more than two "entities"?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is already asked on ELL.

Comment: Rule 1: A gives a gift to B and B gives a gift to A ... they give gifts to each other. / A gives gifts to B, C, D ... and B gives gifts to A, C, D ... etc ... they give gifts to one another. //// I agree, the next scenario is really a different usage. F follows E, who is following D, who is following ... A: 'they 'follow one another'. But nobody follows 'F', and D doesn't follow F ... it's very different.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I had thought of maybe even just two waiters alternating their presence at bussing tables for the whole service

Comment: I'd say that is so far from the default sense that it at the very least contravenes a Gricean maxim. ' ... took turns following each other ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Maybe it's a shortened version of "one AFTER another" ? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/one-after-another

Comment: They've both been around longer even than me ([Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=followed+one+another%2Cfollowed+one+after+another&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfollowed%20one%20another%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfollowed%20one%20after%20another%3B%2Cc0)).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Careful!  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=follows+one+another%2Cfollows+one+after+another%2Cfollows+one+after+the+other&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=9&case_insensitive=true

Comment: I'm not sure what the 'yielded only one result' caveats mean. The graphs should be largely flatlines.